# WebBrowserでリンククリック時に起動するブラウザを既に開いている場合は新しいタブを作成して表示したい。

Tags: c#

C#のWebBrowser内のリンクをクリックしたとき、IE等で新しいウインドウを作成して表示しますが、既にブラウザを開いている場合はそのブラウザに新しいタブを作成して表示したいのですが何か方法はありますか？

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 「IE等」という記述はIE以外も含まれているのでしょうか？ またCookieなどのセッション引継ぎについてはどうされるのでしょうか？ （別サイトへの接続を前提とした質問でしょうか）

Comment: ブラウザは可能であれば複数のものでできるようにしたいのですが、IEのみ、Chromeのみでも問題ありません。Cookieやセッションの引継ぎは特に考えておらず、単純なWebページを一つのウインドウでタブ表示にしたいというものです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebBrowser`コントロールは複数種ありますが、いずれも`Navigating`イベントが備わっているのでこのタイミングで`e.Cancel`に`true`を設定したうえで独自の処理を行えばよいです。

ブラウザーにタブを追加する標準的な手法はないと思いますが、たとえばIE限定で新規タブを表示する方法としては以下のようなものがあるようです。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713206/launch-a-url-in-a-tab-in-an-existing-ie-window-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

補足です。

一般的なブラウザの「タブ」機能は、「ブラウザというアプリケーション」が実装している機能です。

WebBrowser コントロールは、一般的なブラウザの「単独のページを表示する」機能を切り出してコンポーネント化したものなので、「タブ」機能を WebBrowser コントロール単体で実現することは出来ないのです。